# JQ adding count of nested array objects to CSV

Tags: arrays, json, nested, jq

Working with a nested arrays like this:

```
[
    {
        "value1": "Data1-0",
        "value2": "Data2-0",
        "nArray": [
            {"nValue1": "nData1-0a","nValue2": "nData2-0a"},
            {"nValue1": "nData1-0b","nValue2": "nData2-0a"},
            {"nValue1": "nData1-0c","nValue2": "nData2-0a"}
        ],
        "value3": "Data3-0"
    },
    {
        "value1": "Data1-1",
        "value2": "Data2-1",
        "nArray": [
            {"nValue1": "nData1-1a","nValue2": "nData2-1a"},
            {"nValue1": "nData1-1b","nValue2": "nData2-1a"}
        ],
        "value3": "Data3-1"
    }
]
```

Desired output is CSV format like this:

```
Value1,Value2,nArrayCount
Data1-0,Data2-0,Data3-0,3
Data1-1,Data2-1,Data3-1,2
```

I was able to get the nested values but that produces multiple rows for each nArray value with this:

```
[.[] | [.value1,.value2,.value3] + (.nArray[]? | [.nValue1]) ] | .[] | @csv
```

All I need is a count.

Answer (score 0):

Close enough. Use [`length`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#length) to get the length of an array.

```
$ jq -r '
["Value1", "Value2", "count"],
(.[] | [.value1, .value2, (.nArray|length)])
| @csv' input.json
"Value1","Value2","count"
"Data1-0","Data2-0",3
"Data1-1","Data2-1",2
$ jq -r '
["Value1", "Value2", "count"],
(.[] | [.value1, .value2] + [.nArray|length])
| @csv' input.json
"Value1","Value2","count"
"Data1-0","Data2-0",3
"Data1-1","Data2-1",2
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is like the one in your post (no double quotes or comma in Values), then :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
    
jq -r '["Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "nArrayCount"],
       (.[] | [.value1, .value2, .value3, (.nArray|length)])
       | join(",")' input.json
```